# Multiple Join with OR condition Using Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm trying to do `GroupJoin()` with **OR** condition using lambda expression, but I cannot get it done since I don't know if that can be done using `GropuJoin`.

Shorter version of tables:

```
Users
-UserID PK
-Username

UserDetails
-UserDetailID PK
-SectorID FK
-UserID FK

Sectors
-SectorID PK
-SectorName

SectorUser
-SectorUserID PK
-FirstSectorID FK
-SecondSectorID FK
```

BL function looks like this: `GetAllConnectedUsers(int userId)`

So, I need all users that are connected over the `SectorUser` table.

Problem is, as you can see, that `SectorID` of the current user can be in both `FirstSectorID` and `SecondSectorID`.

I have some ideas how to use pure LINQ, but I would like to get it done with Lambda expressions.

Comment: What's the difference between "pure LINQ" and lambda expressions? Do you mean comprehensive syntax vs. fluent syntax? If so, that's only a cosmetic difference.

Comment: What exactly you want to join, what would be the join conditions, what would be the return type of GetAllConnectedUsers?

Comment: @lisp List<User> would be returned.

Comment: Could you give some pseudo-linq to show exactly what you want GetAllConnectedUsers to do, because it's really unclear at this point.

Comment: @lisp If I had SectorID of the User, it would look like something like this in SQL:

`SELECT DISTINCT u.UserID, u.Username
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserDetails ud ON ud.UserID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN UserSector us ON us.FirstSectorID =  ud.SectorID OR us.SecondSectorID = ud.SectorID
WHERE @sectorID = UserSector.FirstSectorID OR @sectorID = UserSector.SecondSectorID`

Comment: What navigation properties have you got? Could you show the classes? It could be as simple as a Union of two navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold Classes are generated by Linq-To-Sql. Nothing additional.

Comment: Then you should be able to Union the two `SectorUser` collections in `Sector`.